# Base $b$ such that as many $x_b$ divide $x$ in set $\mathcal{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Assume $d|n$ means that integer $d$ divides integer $n$. Define
>   $\chi^k$ to be the $k$-th element in a set. Consider the set
>   $\mathcal{Q} =\{1, 2, 3, \dots, 2019\}$. For a base $b$ such that
>   $1<b<2019$, the amount of elements $\chi^k$ in the set $\mathcal{Q}$ such
>   that $\chi^k | {\chi^k}_b$, is maximum. If $d_b$ means $d$ in base $b$, find
>   $b$.

This is a problem I made.

I started by thinking about how we can turn something in base $10$ into base $b$. We have $b^{e_1} + b^{e_2} + b^{e_3} +\cdots +b^{e_n} = \chi$, where $e_n$ is an exponent. We know that $b>10$, as it is necessary. I have no idea where to go from here, as there is nothing I can do. Someone help me out?

Comment: The last two sentences in the highlighted problem does not make sense. Can you reply a translation?

Comment: I wanted to say that there is a base $b$ such that the number of elements in set Q that divide itself in base b is maximum. sorry for my poor english.

Comment: I see. So if zero was in the list, then that would be the number (since every number divides zero).

Comment: Yeah, but the base should be nonzero. I should add that.